# DWR Servlet Exception: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, dwr

I followed the quick steps to configure DWR in my web application (http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html).

When the setup phase ends and I try to access my "localhost:8080/[myAppPath]/dwr/", a NumberFormatException is thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.init(DwrServlet.java:77)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
org.directwebremoting.util.VersionUtil.loadProperties(VersionUtil.java:119)
org.directwebremoting.util.VersionUtil.getLabel(VersionUtil.java:99)
org.directwebremoting.impl.StartupUtil.logStartup(StartupUtil.java:157)
org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.init(DwrServlet.java:62)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I did just as the DWR Tutorials says and I've tried youtube tutorials, googling and even here on stackoverflow and the people who had the same problem didn't get answers.

Here's my servlet declaration on my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dwr.xml</param-value>     
     </init-param>

</servlet>
```

And here's my dwr.xml:

```
<dwr>
   <allow>
      <create creator="static" javascript="DWRManager">
           <param name="class" value="negocio.DWRManager"/>
      </create>
   </allow>
</dwr>
```

**What could be causing this exception?**

I have downloaded DWR 3.0 and put dwr.xml in the same folder as web.xml (WEB-INF)

Comment: Do you have your  servlet code? if so please post it

Answer (score 1):

> org.directwebremoting.util.VersionUtil.loadProperties(VersionUtil.java:119)

it seems to be internal DWR bug in org.directwebremoting.util.VersionUtil class:

```
major = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(KEY_MAJOR));
```

cannot parse value in "dwr-version.properties" file for some reason.

try using latest stable version advertised on their website 2.0.10. it seems DWR 3 isn't really ready for widespread use yet.